# WordPress - AJAX call returns 0

Tags: wordpress, jquery

I am developing a WordPress plugin, and everything works fine. Only problem is, I have an ajax call in jQuery to some code in a php file. It works but it is just a few php commands in a file. That is bad practice in WP, everything should be in a function and attached using a hook.

this is the code in output.php

```
if(isset($_POST['test']) && $_POST['test'] == 'ON'){
    if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        $productId  = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', "", $_POST['id']));
        if ($productId > 1){
            $results = get_option( 'test_options' );
            $result = $results[$productId];
            unset($results);
            echo json_encode($result);
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

this is the AJAX-call in jQuery script

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "output.php",
        data: {
            'test'  : "ON",
            'id'    : productId
        }, 
        success: function(results) {
            result = $.parseJSON(results);
            createArray(result);
        }
    });
```

This works fine. But when I change the code in output.php into a function and use action hook like this:

```
function getInfo(){
    $test   = $_POST['test']);
    $id = $_POST['id']);

    if(isset($test) && ($test == "ON")){
        $result = '';
        if(isset($id)){
            if ($id > 1){
                $results = get_option( 'test_options' );
                $result = $results[$id];
                echo json_encode($result);
                die();
            }
        }
    }
}


add_action('wp_ajax_getInfo','getInfo');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getInfo','getInfo');
```

and change the jQuery script to:

```
$.ajax({
        url: my_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action  : 'getInfo',
            test    : "ON",
            id  : productId
        }, 
        cache: false,
        success: function(results) {
            result = $.parseJSON(results);
            console.log(result);
            alert("succes");
            createArray(result);
        }
    });
```

it doesn't work. What am I missing? I have checked a lot of questions on stackoverflow describing sort of the same problem, checked the solutions but can't find where I go wrong.

Comment: This might be better in the WordPress Answers Stack Exchange.

Comment: Have you modified the stock behavior of WordPress? The AJAX `url` variable is simply `ajaxurl` by default. In the console in your browser, does `my_ajax_script.ajaxurl` point to anything?

Comment: @jterry I have this `wp_localize_script( 'products_Scriptfile', 'my_ajax_script', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
`. If I remove that and change 'my_ajax_script.ajaxurl' to 'ajaxurl' I get an errormessage about 'ajaxurl is undefined'

Comment: @Denis I didn't know about a section dedicated to WordPress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally started working once I added the code of the output.php file to the file that held the `wp_localize_script()` command for the AJAX url.

For frontend use of AJAX calls you need this command to make AJAX available. In admin area AJAX is available by default.